# "Any" followed by singular or plural countable nouns?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

This question has troubled me for ages despite my several attempts of looking it up in dictionaries or usage books. Do we say, "Do you have *any ideas*" or "Do you have *any idea*"? I do see an example where "any" means "it doesn't matter who/which/what", therefore "You can borrow *any book* you like." Also, does it matter between using it in questions and negatives?

Comment: english.stackexchange.com/questions/111444/any-individual-or-any-individuals possible duplicate.

Comment: This is what comes from looking in dictionaries and usage books for grammar information. It's not there, sorry. And that's not how _any_ works. It can modify either plural count nouns or singular mass nouns, which means that any singular noun modified by _any_ is automatically interpreted as a mass noun. That's what happens to _idea_; it is interpreted as meaning 'thought; mentation'. This is not all that surprising, since, while _idea_ is usually a count noun, it is hard to distinguish ***an** idea* from _**some** idea_. Ideas are not notably countable.

Comment: english.stackexchange.com/questions/75654/any-requirement-or-any-requirements another possible duplicate.

Comment: Before asking any question check previous posts. Any questions?

Comment: @John Lawler Women _are_ notably countable. 'Ask any woman' is acceptable. Are you saying that there is a non-obvious massification (implying womankind) here?

Comment: https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv303.shtml#:~:text=Any%20is%20normally%20used%20with,%3F%20~%20Yes%2C%20we%20do.

Answer (score 73):

It depends on the context. If a group of people is brainstorming (that is, trying to come up with a bunch of creative possibilities to solve a problem), then I might ask someone "Do you have any ideas?" In this situation, I am expecting that they may have several ideas that are relevant to the problem.

However, if I am asking for an answer to a specific question, I might say something like, "I can't remember what the capital of Pakistan is, do you have any idea?" In this situation, I am expecting that they might have one specific piece of information to offer. This is probably a more colloquial or idiomatic expression than the other one.

And yes, the use of "any" does have a lot to do with questions and negatives. "Any" is a negative polarity item, which means it can only happen in certain contexts. For example, I would never say "I have any ideas" or "I have any books", but I would say "I don't have any ideas" and "I don't have any books". I don't really know how to give you a full explanation of where or why "any" can be used though. The example you give about borrowing "any book" is certainly correct, even though it isn't negative or a question.

Answer (score 27):

I've been teaching English for almost five years now. My students have had this question before.

According to the books I've used (specifically *Smart Choice* by Oxford University Press and *English in Mind* by Cambridge), "any" is used only for uncountable nouns and plurals and when the sentence is a question or a negative. In the example above about "Do you have any ideas? / Do you have any idea?" consider that "Do you have any idea?" is using *idea* as a synonym of *notion* which in turn is uncountable. You would never use "any" for a singular noun you can count. Could you say "Do you have any books? / Do you have any book?"?

Remember that formulas exist in languages but we humans can break them, like the "adjective before a noun" formula in "it came upon a midnight clear" or "All remaining passengers must wait in the lounge / All passengers remaining must wait in the lounge."

In college I was taught that languages evolve because the people who use the language bend the rules. We invent the language, therefore we can re-invent it and reverse the rules at whim.

Comment: The restriction "when the sentence is a question or a negative" is incorrect, e.g. "Any answer is better than no answer." or "Any answer will do."

Comment: I agree. I like the definitions on Google (which I think are from the OED?). Idea can mean "a thought or suggestion" (countable), or "a concept or mental impression" (uncountable).

Comment: @peak, What does "Senior Research Specialist" mean? You study English?

Comment: @Pacerier - It’s the official title and means what it says, assuming it is parsed as “Senior (Research Specialist)”. Alas, I do not get paid to study English.

Comment: Is _notion_ uncountable?

Answer (score 3):

It may be worth pointing out that *both* `Do you have any ideas?` and `Do you have any idea?` are potentially correct, though they have very different meanings and the latter would normally only be used in a very specific context, e.g. rhetorically, as in:

```
Do you have any idea how much trouble you’ve caused? Do you have any idea?
```