# "Any question" versus "any questions"

Tags: grammatical-number

What is the proper use of question versus questions. For example, 
"Please call me with any question (or questions) you may have."

My boss and I are having an argument over this.

Comment: Your boss is right.

Comment: Related question: ["Any" followed by singular or plural countable nouns?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112996/any-followed-by-singular-or-plural-countable-nouns)

Comment: Mitch is right.

Answer (score 1):

Your audience may have 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or any number of questions.  To cover all the cases (well, you don't need to cover zero), use the plural.

(If you really can't come to an agreement with your boss, you could always compromise with "Please call me with any question(s) you may have." — but that's unnecessarily ugly.)